# How do I get sublime text to use the default version of ruby in it's build command?

Tags: ruby, text-editor

How do I get sublime text to use the default version of ruby in it's build command? When I use the new hash syntax with sublime texts build system it uses an older version of ruby. How can I make it use the default version?

Answer (score 0):

I use this [Ruby.sublime-build](https://gist.github.com/pmarreck/2367908) in my ~/Library/Application/Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/ folder.  It should work with sublime text 2 as well.